# Legend box out of boundary when saving with ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

I've placed my legend horizontally (5 categories) below my barpchart, within r this works fine, but when I save my plot as a picture some categories from the legend disappear or are out of boundary of the plot/picture. I used `ggsave("myPlot.png", p, units = "cm", dpi = 600)` in which `p` represents my plot. Should I fix this within my `ggplot` call or within `ggsave()` and how? I want a smaller length of the complete legend box (in the final saved picture). I've included the picture, so you can see how the legend went wrong. Help is appreciated! Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It looks like `ggsave`'s default dimensions are messing with the relative sizes of the plot elements, leading to a cut off legend. Try `ggsave("myPlot.png", p, units = "cm", dpi = 600, scale = 2)`, or even `scale = 3`. Or specify `width` and `height` arguments to control the overall output size.

Comment: Playing with `width` and `height` works, just need to try a few times, thanks, if you here about an automatic option, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save_plot()` from the `cowplot` package avoids this

instead of:

`ggsave("myPlot.png", p)`

try:

`save_plot("myPlot.png", p)`

Comment: strangely, even if I use save_plot I get the cut off... is there anything else I can do?  I also tried cowplot::save_plot(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `theme(legend.box.margin = margin())` and pad the right margin so it doesn't get cut off. I had the same problem when combining plots using `cowplot::plot_grid()` and adding the legend separately.